# Meteor data context with collectionFS

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

I want to get the `fave.title` within the collectionFS `each` block where I have "TITLE HERE", any ideas?

```
<template name="myFaves">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
            <h2>Your Favourites</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {{#each faves}}
                    {{> singleFave }}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="singleFave">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="freewall" class="freewall">
            {{#each getMedia this.fileId}}
                {{#if isImage store='thumb'}}
                    <div class="brick">
                        <img src="{{this.url store='thumb'}}" width="100%">
                        <div class="info">
                            TITLE HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You need to be more explicit. Is `fave.title` a field of your `faves` collection documents?

Comment: it is a field that is available in the {{> singleFave}} template but when I then go into the getMedia helper this becomes the collectionFS entity, i would like access to the data available in singleFave but one level deeper.

Comment: It works! I didn't know you could do that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to access the parent context. Try it with `{{../fave.title}}` or `{{fave.title ..}}`.

Note that grand-parent context could also be reached using `{{../.. fave.title}}`